# i am trying to do multiple edittext addtextchangedlistener but app crashes

Tags: kotlin, android-edittext, addtextchangedlistener

I have 2 edittexts in my application. When I start to write a value in any of these 2 edittexes, I want to see the result in the other. But when I start typing value in any edittex I get an error

```
private fun initListener() {
        var money = 0.0
        binding.apply {
            monayValueEditText1.addTextChangedListener {
                val money1position = moneyValueSpinner1.selectedItemPosition
                val money2position = moneyValueSpinner2.selectedItemPosition
                money = if (it!!.isEmpty()) 0.0 else
                    it.toString().toDouble()
                val result =
                    ((currencyList[money1position].ForexBuying!! / currencyList[money1position].Unit!!.toDouble()) * money) / currencyList[money2position].ForexBuying!! / currencyList[money2position].Unit!!.toDouble()
                monayValueEditText2.setText(DecimalFormat("##.####").format(result).toString())
            }
            monayValueEditText2.addTextChangedListener {
                money = if (it!!.isEmpty()) 0.0 else
                    it.toString().toDouble()
                val money1position = moneyValueSpinner1.selectedItemPosition
                val money2position = moneyValueSpinner2.selectedItemPosition
                val result =
                    ((currencyList[money2position].ForexBuying!! / currencyList[money2position].Unit!!.toDouble()) * money) / currencyList[money1position].ForexBuying!! / currencyList[money1position].Unit!!.toDouble()
                monayValueEditText1.setText(DecimalFormat("##.####").format(result).toString())
            }

        }

    }
```

the error message i get is like this hundreds of

```
xt(TextView.java:6147)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:121)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6099)
        at com.metoer.ceptedovizborsa.view.fragment.CallculationCurrencyFragment$initListener$lambda-3$$inlined$addTextChangedListener$default$2.afterTextChanged(TextView.kt:104)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:10602)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6328)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6147)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:121)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6099)
```

Comment: Can you share the error log as well? At a first glance I'm seeing a lot of force-unwraps (i.e. `!!`) Are you sure all those variables are non-null by the time you're accessing them?

Comment: yes i am sure it is full the problem is that when i start typing value in one edittext the other edittext in changed event works and as a result it conflicts

Comment: I also shared the error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in getting two `EditText`s that work together, I'm thinking you could do it the [Two-way databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) way in the XML and keep the text in a `ViewModel` instead.

```
<layout ...>

  <data>

      <variable 
          name="viewModel"
          type="com.mypackage.MyViewModel"

  </data>

  ...

  <EditText
       android:id="@+id/monayValueEditText1"
       android:text="@={viewModel.text}"
       ... />

  <EditText
       android:id="@+id/monayValueEditText2"
       android:text="@={viewModel.text}"
       ... />

</layout>
```

Comment: my problem is not being able to give text in edit text. My problem is that as soon as I start to enter a value in edit text, the addTextchanged event of the other editext works and the application crashes in this endless loop.

Comment: Yes, I hear you. AddTextChanged is not sophisticated enough to know when not to act on a text change. It's whether user input OR calling setText programmatically, they both result in TextWatcher getting triggered and results in a loop and eventually the crash. What you should do is to seperate text watching from text setting. Two-way databinding is the way. Above code not only sets a text, but also watches its change. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way

Comment: You need to edit your answer to retract my vote. 
just write a few things and I will withdraw my vote

Comment: I just hyperlinked "Two-way databinding" in the answer so that it is clear what I'm suggesting

Comment: ok i got my vote back can you take it back too

Comment: Will do if you can edit your question with the complete error message. Beggining of the error is cut off

Comment: i can hardly get the error message the phone crashes

Comment: I looked at the error message, she wrote this message 100 times

Comment: You should be seeing it in Android Studio's "Run" tab instead of "Logcat"

Comment: I see and shared the error message.

Comment: there are only 100s of this error message

Comment: So where's the error message? I'm only seeing the stack trace. Anyways just edit something so I can pull back my vote

Comment: I edited it and the error message is below my code, by the way, not in the comment section.

Comment: Yes @ÖmerSeyfettinYavuzyiğit I see the message. It's just partly there. It starts with `xt(TextView.java:6147)` I expected to see a message like `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` or something like that.